# what is equal to np.linalg.solve(A, B) of Python in eigen C++

Tags: c++, numpy, eigen

```
#!/usr/bin/python
x = np.linalg.solve(A, B)
```

The above can calculate the root of *Ax = B*, here, A is a 3 by 3 matrix and B is a 3 by 1 vector. And I want to find a function in Eigen Library with **the same function**, instead of Python Numpy Library. 
The result *x* is right using Python *Numpy linalg.solve()*. The matrix A and B is shown below:

```
A: 
  64  256 1024
  48  256 1280
  24  192 1280
B: 
-9
 0
 0
```

However, I choose the following code (C++ Eigen) to solve the same problem, the error is shown to me.

```
// C++ with Eigen Library
auto x = A.colPivHouseholderQr().solve(B)
```

The above code has an error in running time:

```
frenet: /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/QR/ColPivHouseholderQR.h:546: void
 Eigen::ColPivHouseholderQR<MatrixType>::_solve_impl(const RhsType&, 
DstType&) const [with RhsType = Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1>; DstType = 
Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1>; _MatrixType = Eigen::Matrix<double, -1,
 -1>]: Assertion `rhs.rows() == rows()' failed.
```

I don't know what happens. Wish you could help me soon!

Comment: Could you provide more information on `A, B, x` ? In both cases, did you compare Ax with B? Besides, a MWE would be useful. Did you check that `A` is full rank?

Comment: Linear solvers (specifically iterative solvers) will work to a specific tolerance based on the residuals.

Comment: @Damien If A is not full rank, what would happen?

Comment: If A is not full rank, you will have no valid x solution, or an infinite number of solutions

Comment: Maybe show the two results?

Comment: What you show is a 3x3 matrix but you mention that A is 4x4. Please clarify.

Comment: @20knots I have mistaken it. The size of matrix is 3 by 3.

Comment: I have complete the problem. Thank you for all your reply. I still need your help.

Comment: @Damien The matrix A is full rank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `A` is known at compiletime to be 3x3, I'd recommend calculating the inverse directly (only once if you need it multiple times)

```
#include <Eigen/LU>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  Eigen::Matrix3d A;
  A << 64, 256, 1024, 48, 256, 1280, 24, 192, 1280;
  Eigen::Vector3d B;
  B << -9.0, 0, 0;
  Eigen::Matrix3d A_inv = A.inverse();
  Eigen::Vector3d x = A_inv * B;

  std::cout << "solution x=\n" << x << "\n\nresidual A*x-B=\n" << A * x - B << '\n';
}
```

For larger `A` you need to pick [one of the decompositions](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TopicLinearAlgebraDecompositions.html) which best suits your problem.

Also, be very careful with using `auto` together with Eigen expressions: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/TopicPitfalls.html#TopicPitfalls_auto_keyword

Comment: ```auto``` is responsible for the above problem. Thank you!